# R Error message: invalid type (list) for variable

Tags: r, debugging

Basically, I've made linear regressions with my dataset and now I am having to also add a new dataset so I can add an extra variable. I want to answer another one of my research hypothesis. I think I'm not adding the dataset in properly or something because this is the error code I am getting:
Error in model.frame.default(formula = mh_w3 ~ malaise_50 + CW3_FRTVEGSP + : invalid type (list) for variable 'malaise_50'

This is the code used:
malaise_50<- read.csv(file.choose())
malaise_50<- unlist(malaise_50)

malaise_50<-na.omit(malaise_50)

lm_3 <-lm(mh_w3~ CW3_FRTVEGSP+malaise_50+CW3_FINANCIALMAND+n622,data = data)

All the variables for the linear regression have already been made, the linear regression has been ran without the new variable (malaise_50) and works, but it doesn't run with the new variable.
Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

[The image shows the data I am using in the malaise_50 variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1HjK.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You only removed NA observations in the `malaise_50` dataset, not in the `data` dataset.

Assuming your new dataset `malaise_50` is of the same number of rows (observations) as `data`. You will need to first merge it into `data`, then omit all observations with NA's in data, then run linear regression on `data`:

```
data <- cbind(data, malaise_50) # merge
data <- na.omit(data) # remove NA
lm(..., data = data) # lm
```

The merging part might be different if you have a variable as the matching IDs.

Comment: My new dataset doesn't have the same number of rows. It's from a longitudinal study, from a different time point. When i try the suggested code this is the error I get: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3166, 9618